# Night Light disabled in Action Center

Tags: windows-10

Today, when I opened my action center to turn on Night Light, the Night Light button was greyed out and was not clickable. Nothing seemed to turn it on. Initially, I thought that it was a time related issue, though I had not set a schedule for turning it on and off, but changing the time made no difference.

Is there any way to get it back quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that your time zone is properly configured and your clock is updated to the current internet time.

Then go to Settings -- System -- Display and turn on Night Light manually from there. The button should now be re-enabled.

Comment: Seriously don't understand the downvote. This actually solves the issue.

Comment: "(Maybe a restart would help too, but I couldn't try it, since I had a hundred tabs open)" - that is commentary.

Comment: @Ramhound, removed it, though I'm not sure if I fully agree with you...

Comment: I read a statement like that, and either think you are not willing to verify the statement before you make it, or you simply don't want to verify it for whatever reason.  In either case, since I expect an answer to be written from an authoritative position, the comment/statement itself seems extremely weak.

Comment: @Ramhound it was just meant as a suggestion to anyone else who may have the same problem that may not be solved by my solution. In case you haven't realized, it is not about me not willing or wanting to verify it, but being *unable* to verify it, since now that I have already solved the problem, I first need to recreate it to try other solutions (of course I don't know how).

Comment: If I wanted to read suggestions instead of answers, I would go to Yahoo Answers or Quora, and I despise both of those places.

Comment: @RadialApps Settings -- System -- Display -- **Turn On** button is disabled? How do I get it back?